# C# mysql read int32 strange behavior

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql table such as

```
   CREATE TABLE `bs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ma_nguoitao` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma_nguoitao_dv` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma_nguoi_bilap` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma_nguoi_bilap_dv` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma_loi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noi_dung` blob,
  `phan_hoi` blob,
  `ngay_lap` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ket_luan` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tinh_trang` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma_bill` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `phat_chatluong` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phat_denbu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  `) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I saved data using

```
             dbManager.com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bs(`id`,`ma_nguoitao`,`ma_nguoitao_dv`,`ma_nguoi_bilap`,`ma_nguoi_bilap_dv`,`ma_loi`,`noi_dung`,`phan_hoi`,`ngay_lap`,`ket_luan`,`tinh_trang`,`ma_bill`,`phat_chatluong`,`phat_denbu`) "+
                "VALUES(?id, ?nt, ?ntdv, ?nbl, ?nbldv, ?ml, ?nd, ?ph, ?nl, ?kl, ?tt, ?mb, ?pcl, ?pdb )"+
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ma_loi=VALUES(`ma_loi`), noi_dung=VALUES(`noi_dung`), phan_hoi=VALUES(`phan_hoi`), ket_luan=VALUES(`ket_luan`), tinh_trang=VALUES(`tinh_trang`), phat_chatluong=VALUES(`phat_chatluong`), phat_denbu=VALUES(`phat_denbu`)";
                dbManager.com.Prepare();
                MySqlCommand temp = dbManager.con.CreateCommand();
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                temp.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
                temp.Prepare();

                foreach (BASE_BIENBAN_LOI_ENTITY obj in list)
                {
                    if (obj.ma_bill.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?id", obj.id);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?nt",obj.ma_nguoitao); 
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?ntdv", obj.ma_nguoitao_donvi);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?nbl",obj.ma_nguoi_bi_lap);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?nbldv", obj.ma_nguoi_bi_lap_donvi);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?ml", obj.ma_loi);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?nd", obj.noi_dung);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?nl", System.DateTime.Now);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?ph", obj.phan_hoi);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?kl", obj.ket_luan);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?tt", obj.tinh_trang);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?mb", obj.ma_bill);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?pcl", obj.phat_chatluong);
                        dbManager.com.Parameters.Add("?pdb", obj.phat_denbu);
                        dbManager.com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        reader = temp.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            obj.id = (int)(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
```

`obj.phat_chatluong` is defined as `int`. My problem is that when I read value from `phat_chatluong` field, the value seem interpret as ascii byte array instead of `int`. For example, a record has `phat_chatluong=40`, when I read it using

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ma_bill ,id, ma_nguoitao, ma_nguoitao_dv,"+
                    "ma_nguoi_bilap, ma_nguoi_bilap_dv, ma_loi, noi_dung,"+
                    "phan_hoi, ngay_lap, ket_luan, tinh_trang, phat_chatluong, phat_denbu FROM bs_bienban", con);
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            int phat_chatluong = (int) reader["phat_chatluong"];
```

then I got 0x3430 as value of `phat_chatluong` , that's so strange?, Where I was wrong?

Comment: The piece of code you have provided beneath `I saved data using` is irrelevant if you can confirm what the value in the database actually is. Could you copy/paste the data of the row its about? (using MySQL WorkBench for example?). That way you can either exclude your insert or read code as the origin of the problem. But you can read ints: `obj.id = (int)(reader.GetInt32(0));` have you tried that exact same line for `phat_chatluong`? Like so `obj.id = (int)(reader.GetInt32("phat_chatluong"));`? What is the result returned?

Comment: `obj.phat_chatluong` is defined as `int` and I can confirm that its value=`40` when I do insert the record.

Comment: this is data I copy from Navicat `112233445566778 7 giang 70001 giang1 itdev 1 13-09-2013 09:42:26: faffffafafd
  2013-09-13 09:42:38 0 1 40 55
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! It seem that the project that I work on use an old MySql Connector/Driver, it's ok now on new version of MySql Connector.

Comment: I'm interested in what version of the connector you were using before, and the version of the connector you are using now.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: it's version is 1.0.4 20163, the other point is this problem only occur after I added(alter) new fields to an exist table, the reading error is occur on these new fields.